# Pass php results to another website.

Tags: php, javascript, html

So what I am trying to do is this:

On my server users can put there YouTube channel name. My php file will then parse the channel and output HTML code with results. What I am looking to do is for the users to be able to put a code on there website that till call on my website lets say `youtubevideos.com/videos.php?channel=channelname` my code will take that name and output the videos back to there site. much like Google ads I guess.

Any idea how that is done, other than an iframe, I figured that will be my last resort.

I think what I'm looking for if for them to put a JavaScript on there site that will render as the HTML code I'm pushing from my php file.

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't it a sort of API? In this case , ask your members to include a SDK file or script to send requests to your server.

Comment: if you don't have an API you could try `CURL` (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Note: you need to have `CURL` enabled on your server.

Comment: Have you checked that Youtube are ok with you content-scraping their website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The receiver code which is on the server you target need to set a header like that :

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*"
```

So, if you provide a service which need to exchange with your server & your code, is it possible. If you can't edit the targeted code & the header is not setted, it'll be impossible

Answer (score 1):

There would be two parts of this solution.

In the `videos.php` file on your server, you would implement the logic to scrape the data from the original site and format it in the way you want to show on the final website.

For the end user, you would give a code similar to this that they would have to paste in their php pages to display the content from your site.

```
$your_website_url="http://youtubevideos.com/videos.php?channel=channelname";
//Don't forget the http:// at the start.

echo file_get_contents($your_website_url);
```

If `file_get_contents()` gives a security error, you can use [curl](/questions/tagged/curl).

I hope that helps.